# Context.User is Nothing ONLY when trying to debug

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.0

I have a project that I have upgraded from .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0.  The project uses Windows Authentication (internal Intranet webpage).  I setup Windows Authentication in IIS 7.5 (running Windows 7) following the steps laid out in this article.

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication

I can now build the project.  I can open the project by opening IE and typing in the URL on localhost.  However, if I try to debug the project it throws an NullReferenceException on this line in the Application_AuthenticateRequest in Global.asax.

```
dt = oDBLookup.GetPIMSUserRoles(Context.User.Identity.Name)
```

If I set a breakpoint there I see that Context.User is Nothing.  If I set a breakpoint in the same place on the 1.1 project (different box, running IIS 6) it has my Windows Credentials.

Why would Context.User be Nothing ONLY when I am trying to run from the debugger in Visual Studio 2010 Professional, and not when I open the web project directly in IE?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be that the VS is hosting the site when you run debug (F5), not IIS. Try attaching IE to the debugger and see if you get a value for Context.User.

Comment: Sorry, I knew that VS uses it's own Web server since 2005.  I can't see any settings in VS for Windows Authentication, though, and unlike some previous versions I don't see a use IIS option where the Use Default Web server is currently selected.

Comment: If you go to the project's properties, under the Web tab, there should be an option to Use Local IIS Web server.  Try setting that.  If you can't find it, try starting a browser, attaching it to the debugger and then hitting your page.

Comment: So I deleted the solution file (which had been upgraded), created a new one in VS 2010 and the problem disappeared.  I would put this as an answer but my reputation is below 100 so I can't answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the solution file (which had been upgraded), created a new one in VS 2010 and the problem disappeared. I would put this as an answer but my reputation is below 100 so I can't answer my own question.